# mod_rewrite on 403 error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-403

I have a .htaccess file that looks like this. What i would like to do is pass the request onto index.php if the file or directory exists and a 403 error was generated as well.

that is, if "/foo/bar" exists on the server, but a 403 is generated i want that "/foo/bar" passed onto index.php as if the directory "/foo/bar" doesn't exist on the server.

possible?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  #Make sure the physical file doesn't exist
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling of error conditions is performed via [`ErrorDocument`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument).

Comment: is it possible to pass all the query and url information to ErrorDocument like with mod-rewrite? Doesn't seem in the docs.

Comment: I'm... going to assume that you didn't actually [read](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html) them...

Comment: simply adding "ErrorDocument 403 /index.php" handles this case.